# XCode Debugger, Expression inspection like Eclipse (Ctrl + Shift + I)

Tags: ios, xcode, eclipse

Under eclipse I can inspect expressions/variables in debug mode with Ctrl+Shift+I. I am new to Xcode and I'm looking for simular functionality for Xcode, nothing found in Stackoverflow.
Is there any way to inspect variables and expression on the fly when I'm debugging? And what is a Shortcut for ?

Comment: Do you want to know the value of the variables while debugging

Comment: Use breakpoints, click on the line number in editor and you'll see blue ribbon. Code execution will stop at this line.

Comment: No, I want to mark an Expression e.g. if (Expression) and would like to know what the result of this Expression is. It is simple if the Expression is only a Boolean variable but if the Expression is more complicated it is annoying to figure what an Expression returns.

Comment: I just want the same behaviour like Eclipse Ctrl + Shift + I , I really miss this feature on Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who have the same problem and are looking for a solution.
I have found a Solution. 
When you set a Breakpoint and you run into the Breakpoint, you can type in in the Output Window ***po*** EXPRESSION or ***po*** [object methodName] and the result or Informations are shown in the output console. see Picture.

[image]